# How can I add a value to a column?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to add a value to an existing column, but I don't want to have to select it first. Right now I would have to do something like

```
// run hql in a named query
from Employee where id = :id

// after running the above
e.setBonus(e.getBonus() + 100); // add 100 to e's bonus

// commit to database
HibernateUtil.saveOrUpdate(e);
```

But I want something that's just one-and-done - something like

```
update Employee e set e.bonus = e.bonus + 100
```

Is this something I can do in Hibernate? If so, how. If not, what's the suggested best practice for such an update?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it as intended with hql query. Try such code:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
String hql="update Employee e set e.bonus = e.bonus + :p where id=:id";
session.createQuery(hql).setInteger("p",100).setInteger("id",id).executeUpdate();
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

More info you can find by the [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#batch-direct)

Comment: I have been corrected the link. And will explain it

Answer (score 0):

You could create a hql query that just does an update

```
Query updateBonus = createQuery("UPDATE Employee SET bonus = bonus+100 WHERE id = :id" );
updateBonus.setInteger("id", employee.getId());
updateBonus.executeUpdate();
```